# DBpedia french abstracts

Tags: rdf, abstract, dbpedia

I noticed a little problem on DBpedia datasets, and I was wondering if someone has already be confronted to it, and how you deal with it.

The problem is that french abstracts contain some noise in their values, for some dates and more generaly literal values of other fields.

For instance : 
William Bradley "Brad" Pitt est un acteur et producteur de cinéma américain né le **Modèle:Date** à Shawnee, dans l'État de l'Oklahoma. Après des débuts à la télévision, il perce au cinéma au début des années 1990 grâce à son rôle de voleur dans Thelma et Louise. Il a depuis joué dans de nombreux films cultes comme Entretien avec un vampire, Seven, L'Armée des 12 singes, Sleepers et Fight Club. Brad Pitt a reçu deux nominations aux Oscars, quatre nominations aux Golden Globe, et en a remporté un en 1995. Il est le premier à avoir été élu deux fois « Homme vivant le plus sexy » par le magazine People, en 1995 et 2000.

or : 
Le quartier de Belleville est le **77Modèle:E** quartier administratif de Paris situé dans le . Dans les représentations des Parisiens, le « quartier de Belleville » est plus vaste. Recouvrant l'ancienne commune de Belleville, de part et d'autre de l'actuelle rue de Belleville, il est à cheval entre le 19ème, 20ème, 10ème, et le 11ème arrondissement de la ville de Paris.

(sources : http://dbpedia.org/page/Brad_Pitt , http://dbpedia.org/page/Belleville,_Paris)

This problem only seems to happen only on french abstracts.

Any idea ?

Comment: I think it these errors are due to the errors in the extraction process. Unfortunately I do not see how you can do anything about it except manually string search them for repeating errors.

Comment: I think so too. But the string search solution can not be a clean one, because of the differences between theses "noises". For instance, on the two examples I gave here, the first one shows that the value has simply been replaced by the noise ! The second one shows that only the special character "è" has been replaced.

Comment: I don't understand how DBpedia can leave that in their database : the abstract field is one of the most important of the datatype-properties ones ! So I ask for a solution : how DBpedia users can properly deal with this problem ? Get Wikipedia pages abstracts for instance ? What are the french DBpedia users advices ?

Comment: The problem is no longer visible. These problems came from the extraction process - it appears that a birth date was replaced by `Modèle:Date` and an ordering number by `Modèle:E`. Bugs like these should be reported to DBpedia.